How to add a custom claim to the access token obtained from Salesforce?
I want to add custom claims to the access token obtained from Salesforce Connected App. I have seen these 2 articles (OpenID Connect - adding custom attributes (claims) to id token and Adding custom claims to access token in oAuth JWT Bearer flow) These are 5 and 4yr old tickets.
Wanted to check if it is possible to add a custom claim to access tokens now?

I'll take this opportunity to clear up some misconceptions that it appears you have. We (Salesforce StackExchange) are not an official part of Salesforce. While there are some Salesforce employees among us, the vast majority of people here are customers of Salesforce like yourself. This is just a community-managed Q&A site/repository of knowledge. These aren't official articles or tickets (help.salesforce.com are the official articles, and ideas.salesforce.com are where we can plead to Salesforce to maybe do something in 10 year's time)

Access token - no, use the ID token. Until very recently, access tokens weren't even available in JWT format.

@DerekF yes I understand that, I wanted to get feedback fellow developers if anyone is aware of new developments in this area since those articles were old. But Salesforce doesn't seem to have changed anything.. Thank you..

After a bit of testing
At time of writing, half yes and half no
custom attributes cannot be added to the access token itself, only the Id token
in some scenarios, the id token (a JWT) can be included in the same response that provides the access token
The best we've got
You can (once Enable OAuth Settings is checked in the Connected App's "edit" page, Setup -> Apps -> App Manager, then find your Connected App, click the triangle, and select edit) check Configure ID Token, which will show some additional checkboxes, one of which is Include Custom Attributes
You'll need to add the Access unique user identifiers (openid) scope too
The custom attributes are managed through the "manage" page for the Connected App (Setup -> Apps -> Connected Apps -> Manage Connected Apps, and find your Connected App's name)
For the Client Credentials flow (and possibly others where a specific user isn't provided in the request)
The response with the access token will include the id key, which contains a url like https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D.../005....
Making a second request using that url (and including the access token (obtained from the first request) in the Authorization header, of course) will get you the Id token, which does contain the custom_attributes
There is no way around needing to make 2 requests in this case
For the Authorization Code flow (a.k.a. the "Web-Server" flow), and likely others
If you don't specifically send data in the scope part of your request body, or if you include the openid scope, you'll get the id token (as a JWT) in the same response as the one that provides the access token.
Some simple processing and Base64Url1 decoding later, you could get at the custom attributes.
If you include scopes in your request but omit the openId scope, the you get the id key with the url as the value, and you'd need to make a second request just like in the "client credentials" case
1: not to be confused with Base64, there are two non-url-safe characters that are replaced in Base64 to make it Base64Url. Salesforce doesn't provide tools specific to Base64Url
